# How to configure authentication with Lumen?

Tags: laravel, authentication, lumen

I want to use Lumen to build my web application, but I don't know how to implement login in this framework.

Does anybody know how?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [authentication documentation for Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) ?

Comment: Lumen has no session support, which is often what people mean by 'logging in'. If you need session support, it is advised to just use Laravel. Otherwise check that authentication section of those docs that Ohgodwhy has posted.